# Eclipse Java assistance doesn't comply with compiler level setting

Tags: java, eclipse

The compiler level used to autocomplete my Java code in Eclipse Neon is 1.8 (proof is it suggests me to use `ResourceBundle::getBaseBundleName()` for example). I do use a 1.8 JDK but the workspace Java compiler compliance level is 1.7 and project specific settings aren't enabled. How come and how do I change that?

Comment: Did you tried to set a specific settings with 1.7 ? (Might be a bug with Neon)

Comment: No change whatsoever.

Comment: Strange, is it the same for a Java Class ? Using a Lambda (or anything) with 1.7 used. The Java editor might be buggy... I will check tonight on my laptop (running on a OLD eclipse at the office)

Comment: You're actually right, the whole Java coding assistance is in 1.8, I just noticed! I'll have to edit my post.

Comment: if you are saying `neon` is buggy then you are true